I'm getting an error when trying to install and configure Next.js with shadcn ui
screenshot of VS code giving error
This is the error message that it is giving:
PS C:\Users\mcken\OneDrive\Desktop\Codedex\GHW> npx shadcn-ui@latest init       
>>
node:fs:573
  return binding.open(
                 ^

Error: package.json: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\mcken\OneDrive\Desktop\Codedex\GHW\package.json'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:573:18)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:452:35)
    at Object.readFileSync (C:\Users\mcken\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\125ee17d583c4e03\node_modules\jsonfile\index.js:50:22)
    at _e (file:///C:/Users/mcken/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/125ee17d583c4e03/node_modules/shadcn-ui/dist/index.js:245:5248)
    at _t (file:///C:/Users/mcken/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/125ee17d583c4e03/node_modules/shadcn-ui/dist/index.js:245:5379)
    at file:///C:/Users/mcken/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/125ee17d583c4e03/node_modules/shadcn-ui/dist/index.js:245:5606
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:222:25)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:316:24)
    at async asyncRunEntryPointWithESMLoader (node:internal/modules/run_main:123:5) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\mcken\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Codedex\\GHW\\package.json'
}

Node.js v20.15.1
I have tried finding what directory I need to add a folder to because it seems that is the problem, but I'm not sure from the error where this would be or what file needs to be added.
